# i use append in for loop of local storage ,i want to display item in a new line every time loop finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, local-storage, shopping-cart

```
for(item in cart){

    let name =cart[item][1];
    let qty =cart[item][0];
    let image =cart[item][2];
    let price=cart[item][3];
    mystr=`  <td class="product-thumbnail"><a href="shop-details.html"><image src="${image}" alt="product"> </a></td>
      <td  class="product-name">${name}</td>
      <td class="product-price"><span class="amount">${price}</span></td>
      <td class="product-quantity">
        <button id='plus" + item + "' class ='btn btn-primary plus'>+</button>
        <span id="quantity" >${qty}</span>
        <button id='minus" + item +"' class='btn btn-primary minus'>-</button>
      </td>
      <td class="product-subtotal"><span class="amount"></span></td>
      <td class="product-remove"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td> `

    console.log(mystr);
    $('#items').append(mystr)
}
```

I expect this:

[image]

But currently, it coming like this:

[image]

Comment: before starting `<td>` and after closing`</td>` add `<tr>` and `</tr>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML string is missing the `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags to tell the browser you need to go to a newline.

Try replacing mystr with:

```js
var mystr = `<tr>
  <td class="product-thumbnail"><a href="shop-details.html">
      <image src="${image}" alt="product">
    </a></td>
  <td class="product-name">${name}</td>
  <td class="product-price"><span class="amount">${price}</span></td>
  <td class="product-quantity">
    <button id='plus" + item + "' class='btn btn-primary plus'>+</button>
    <span id="quantity">${qty}</span>
    <button id='minus" + item +"' class='btn btn-primary minus'>-</button>
  </td>
  <td class="product-subtotal"><span class="amount"></span></td>
  <td class="product-remove"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
</tr>`
```

This should display your content the right way.

Comment: this is a kind of suggestion. Giving answer is not necessary